Unexpected character '@' when migrating from Svelte 4 to Svelte 5
I am migrating a a Svelte 4 app to a Svelte 5 app, I used the npx command line
npx sv migrate svelte-5

This resulted in my <slot /> tag in my layout.svelte file on my front page being replaced with {@render children?.()}.  This creates a Unexpected character '@' error, which I can't resolve.

Where is the error from, IDE or build process? Is the package version in the package.json correctly set to 5 after the migration?

It was getting flagged in both the IDE and the build process.  I just went to replicate the error again,  (I had re-written it back in Svelte4 syntax, but changed it back to Svelte 5) and now it is only in the IDE.  In between I reinstalled svelte 5, I noticed the sv command had installed 5.0.0 so I reinstalled it and now it is 5.2.0
